# Just upgraded react-native-firebase and I am getting errors when I build

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-firebase

I just upgraded react-native (0.57.3) and react-native-firebase (5.1.0-rc1) to the latest versions, and I am receiving these errors when I build:

> /Volumes/EamonWD/snag/react-native-firebase-starter/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/functions/RNFirebaseFunctions.m:26:45: No known class method for selector 'functionsForApp:region:'

The above error happens in two places, I also receive:

> /Volumes/EamonWD/snag/react-native-firebase-starter/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/functions/RNFirebaseFunctions.m:69:16: No visible @interface for 'FIRFunctions' declares the selector
>   'useFunctionsEmulatorOrigin:'

I am using `Cocoapods`, I am guessing maybe something didn't fully update? or link?

This is my `Podfile`:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'snagit' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for snagit

  # Required by RNFirebase
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.3.0'

  # [OPTIONAL PODS] - comment out pods for firebase products you won't be using.
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Functions', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 5.3.0'
  # pod 'Firebase/Invites', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance', '~> 5.3.0'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.5'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.4'

  pod 'FacebookSDK'


  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  pod 'react-native-camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-camera'

  # Fixes required for pod specs to work with rn 0.42
  react_native_path = "../node_modules/react-native"
  pod "yoga", :path => "#{react_native_path}/ReactCommon/yoga"
  pod "React", :path => react_native_path, :subspecs => [
      'Core',
      'RCTActionSheet',
      'RCTAnimation',
      'RCTGeolocation',
      'RCTImage',
      'RCTLinkingIOS',
      'RCTNetwork',
      'RCTSettings',
      'RCTText',
      'RCTVibration',
      'RCTWebSocket',
      'DevSupport'
  ]
  pod 'RNGoogleSignin', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-google-signin'

  pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'

end
```

Is the version correct? (5.3.0). Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: The native Firebase iOS SDKs needs to be at least `5.10.0` for RNFB `v5.1.0`. I'd recommend switching to `v5.1.0-rc3` and also updating your versions to match the ones in the release notes: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/master/release-notes#5.1.0 (full v5.1.0 is pending release for tomorrow)